# How do I email an html table containing mysql result data with a button in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Sorry if this is a poor description, I am relatively new to this.

I am developing a web tool which displays the results of mysql data filtered by a date range in an html table. I have an input and button which allows the user to input an email address to send the table data to. The problem is I am having trouble passing the html table data correctly to my php page to be emailed.

I've tried various methods with AJAX and Javascript, but nothing is working. At one point I was able to pass the table data, but not the inputted email (or vice versa); never both simultaneously. I need to be able to pass both the email that has been inputted as well as the data in the html table preferably reserving the table format as well for a cleaner look). Any help and/or insight is greatly appreciated. Apologies if this code is improper and/or wrong.

Relevant PHP:

```
<!-- download2csv button -->

    <div>
    <form action="getCSV.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="csv_text" id="csv_text_computers">
        <button class="btn btn-app btn-primary btn-xs no-radius" type="submit" onclick="getCSVDataComputers()">
        <i class="icon-save"></i></button>
    </form>

<!-- email button -->

    <form action="mailto.php" method="post">
        Email: <input type="text" name="einame" id="eiid" placeholder="example@example.com">
        <button class="btn btn-app btn-info btn-xs no-radius" type="submit" name="ebname" id="ebid" onclick="mailer()">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i></button>
    </form>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- data table header -->

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="table-computers1" name="table-computers" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>RFID Number</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Delivery Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($infocoms as $infocom)
            {
                //variables for glpi url
                $itemtype = $infocom['itemtype'];
                $items_id = $infocom['items_id'];
                $url = "https://null.null.com/front/" . $itemtype. ".form.php?id=" . $items_id;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <?php
                // database connection
                $conn = mysqli_connect('null', 'null', 'null');
                mysqli_select_db($conn, 'glpi');

                if ($infocom['itemtype'] == "peripheral") {
                    $query = "SELECT glpi_peripherals.name AS devicename, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM glpi_peripherals.otherserial) AS otherserial FROM glpi_peripherals INNER JOIN glpi_infocoms ON glpi_peripherals.id = glpi_infocoms.items_id WHERE glpi_infocoms.items_id = $infocom[items_id] AND glpi_infocoms.itemtype = 'peripheral'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    $devices = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    echo "<td>$devices[devicename]</td>";
                    echo "<td><center>$devices[otherserial]</center></td>";

                } elseif ($infocom['itemtype'] == "computer") {
                    $query = "SELECT glpi_computers.name AS compname, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM glpi_computers.otherserial) AS otherserial FROM glpi_computers INNER JOIN glpi_infocoms ON glpi_computers.id = glpi_infocoms.items_id WHERE glpi_infocoms.items_id = $infocom[items_id] AND glpi_infocoms.itemtype = 'computer'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    $computers = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    echo "<td>$computers[compname]</td>";
                    echo "<td><center>$computers[otherserial]</center></td>";

                } elseif ($infocom['itemtype'] == "monitor") {
                    $query = "SELECT glpi_monitors.name AS viewname, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM glpi_monitors.otherserial) AS otherserial FROM glpi_monitors INNER JOIN glpi_infocoms ON glpi_monitors.id = glpi_infocoms.items_id WHERE glpi_infocoms.items_id = $infocom[items_id] AND glpi_infocoms.itemtype = 'monitor'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    $monitors = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    echo "<td>$monitors[viewname]</td>";
                    echo "<td><center>$monitors[otherserial]</center></td>";

                } elseif ($infocom['itemtype'] == "networkequipment") {
                    $query = "SELECT glpi_networkequipments.name AS netname, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM glpi_networkequipments.otherserial) AS otherserial FROM glpi_networkequipments INNER JOIN glpi_infocoms ON glpi_networkequipments.id = glpi_infocoms.items_id WHERE glpi_infocoms.items_id = $infocom[items_id] AND glpi_infocoms.itemtype = 'networkequipment'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    $networks = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    echo "<td>$networks[netname]</td>";
                    echo "<td><center>$networks[otherserial]</center></td>";

                } elseif ($infocom['itemtype'] == "printer") {
                    $query = "SELECT glpi_printers.name AS printname, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM glpi_printers.otherserial) AS otherserial FROM glpi_printers INNER JOIN glpi_infocoms ON glpi_printers.id = glpi_infocoms.items_id WHERE glpi_infocoms.items_id = $infocom[items_id] AND glpi_infocoms.itemtype = 'networkequipment'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    $printers = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    echo "<td>$printers[printname]</td>";
                    echo "<td><center>$printers[otherserial]</center></td>";

                } else {
                    // error handling for null entries
                    echo "1 or more items were not found";
                }
                // end data loop and close mysql connection
                mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
                <td><a target=_blank href=$url><?php echo $url; ?></a></td>
                <td><center><?php echo $infocom['ddate']; ?></center></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<?php
} else {
    echo "<center><p style='font-size:125%;'>Please select a date range to submit.</p></center>";
}
error_log("\n");
?>
```

Relevant Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var oTable1 = $('#table-computers').dataTable( {
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 100, -1], [10, 25, 100, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": true },
      null, null,null,
    ] } );
})

function getCSVDataComputers(){
var csv_value=$('#table-computers').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
$("#csv_text_computers").val(csv_value);
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function mailer()    
 {    
   var tableContent=document.getElementById("table-computers").innerHTML;
   alert(tableContent); // This works, but data does not echo in mailto.php
   $.post('mailto.php',{content:tableContent},function(data) {
    });
 }

</script>
```

Mailto PHP page:

```
<?php
$mailto = $_POST['einame'];
$table = $_POST['tableContent'];

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Test <test@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

if (isset($mailto)) {
mail($mailto,"GLPI Notifications",$table,$headers);
echo "Mail sent successfully to $mailto." . "\r\n";
} else {
echo "Mail was not sent." . "\r\n";
}

?>

<br>
<a href="blank.php">Home Page</a>
<br>
<?php
echo $table; // Displays nothing
error_log("\n");
?>
```

Comment: In this portion, can't you do something like: `$.post('mailto.php',{ "content": tableContent,"email": $('input[name=einame]').val() },function(data)...`? Wouldn't that send `$_POST['content']` and `$_POST['email']`? Seems like it might.

Answer (score 0):

finally figured it out. updated code:

```
function mailer() {    
   var tableContent=document.getElementById("table-computers").innerHTML;
   // alert(tableContent); confirmation
   $.post("mailto.php",{ "content": $("#bmailto").val(tableContent) },function(data) {
    });
 }
```